# How to upload image using file_get_contents in php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, codeigniter, next.js

I am new In Reactjs and php, I have index.js (page in Reactjs/nextjs) and i am sending image data (using multipart form data) And in Php i am trying to upload image but whenever i am trying to upload image then uploaded image showing error "we dont support this format", So please tell me how can i simply upload image using "file_get_contents" method, Here is my code in php (which is uploading incorrect image or 0 byte image), i tried with 2 ways , First way/code is

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
 $files=file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
 $image = base64_decode(explode( ',', $files)[1]);
 $file_name =$_FILES['file']['name'];
 $file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));
 define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
 $file_ext  = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $file_name = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . time() . '.' . $file_ext;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $file_name);
```

Second way is

```
$file_name =$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.'.$file_ext;
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple upload class that I edit for each project, test it, hope it helps

```
class Upload
{

    //300 kb
    private static $MAX_FILE_SIZE = 300 * 1024;
    private static $ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];
    private static $key;
    private static $ImageFileType;

    public static function uploadTeamLogo($key, $short_name, $relativePath)
    {
        self::$key = $key;

        if (!self::isImage())
            apiErrorMessage("Not an image!");

        if (!self::fileTypeIsAllowed(basename($_FILES[self::$key]["name"])))
            apiErrorMessage("Only png, jpg, jpeg Images are allowed!");

        if (self::isSizeTooLarge())
            apiErrorMessage("Max file size is 300kb!");

        $image_name = $short_name . "_" . generateHash(12) . "." . self::$ImageFileType;

        $target_dir = getcwd() . $relativePath . $image_name;
        if (self::doUpload($target_dir))
            return $image_name;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private static function isImage()
    {
        return getimagesize($_FILES[self::$key]["tmp_name"]) == true;
    }

    private static function alreadyExist($target_file)
    {
        return file_exists($target_file) === true;
    }

    private static function isSizeTooLarge()
    {
        return $_FILES[self::$key]["size"] > self::$MAX_FILE_SIZE === true;
    }

    private static function fileTypeIsAllowed($target_file)
    {
        self::$ImageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        foreach (self::$ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES as $type)
            if (self::$ImageFileType == $type)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static function doUpload($target_file)
    {
        return move_uploaded_file($_FILES[self::$key]["tmp_name"], $target_file) == true;
    }

}
```

use like this:

```
$image_name = Upload::uploadTeamLogo($key, $short_name, $path);
```